# Create multiple Tabs in Pencil Project WIreframing Tool

Tags: wireframe, mockups, mockup-tool

I'm trying ou Pencil Project as a wireframing tool, however I am unable to find out how to create multiple tabs. When I drag the "Tab Panel" control it defaults to one tab, however my wireframe needs multiple tabs.

Answer (score 5):

Double-click on the tab to edit it and add some. Tabs are delimited by | and the selected starts with # so for example a group of 3 tabs with the last one active would be "tab1|tab2|#ta3"

This only works for native UI object which is a huge disadvantage.

Comment: This is correct, but one thing to mention is that it will only work for the "Native UI Widget" library. I was not able to reproduce this with the "Windows XP Widgets".